# Reading metadata in Flutter's webview

Tags: flutter, webview, metadata, webview-flutter

I'm using webview_flutter in a Flutter's app. I need to know the language of the page opened in that webview, maybe reading the "lang=en-us" tag. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can read the `lang` attribute. You can do this by getting the html content itself.
This answer might help - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63244852/14449776)